# KeyUp/KeyDown is only caught once

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to display a Dialog every time the keys BACK or SCAPE are pressed. However the event is only been caught once, dialog is shown but if I close it by pressing my button NO, then it will never appear again until I go to another screen.

This is how I catch the KeyUp event:

```
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {     
    if (keycode == Keys.BACK || keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) {

        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is my button inside of the Dialog:

```
    btnNo.addListener(
            new ClickListener() {
                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
```

If you have any idea ,please let me know...

Comment: Are you trying to keep prompting user if BACK or SPACE has been pressed if so you need to capture the returned value from dialog

Comment: Another way is to create Boolean  and set to false then create a while loop based on your Boolean if true and put your dialog show inside it and if your dialog return  YES then set it the Boolean variable to true so it can exit the while loop else if Dialog NO is pressed set the Boolean variable to false so while loop keep on prompting the user.

Comment: thanks @GeorgeSaad...it is basically a dialog that will display "Exit game? Yes and No buttons".... the dialog is displayed once, but then it stops and as you can see the button NO just set the Dialog visibility to FALSE. Not sure how to capture the returned value from the dialog.

Comment: @GeorgeSaad, ok let me try the second way

Comment: Could you please tell me what framework are you using to let me give syntax.

Comment: @GeorgeSaad, I am using libgdx, a game framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been resolved with the following block code in the Render():

```
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)){
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following site they have clear description on how to use Dialog in LibGDX http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html

Comment: Hi...it has to do with key event not been called. The Dialog itself works fine.

Comment: I'm sure @Devester when you created the instance of the Dialog the option to set the buttons YES and NO  and other values on the touch up event before you set dialog.SetVisible to false perform your check on which button has been pressed e.g if (dialog.Button == "YES") dialog.SetVisible(false); else(dialog.Button == "NO") dialog.SetVisible(true);